# How can I match a list value to a single csv file's row?

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, matching

I need to compare a list of integers values with a single row in a CVS file in order to find which line matches that values.

'''

```
firstScore = 90  
secondScore = 80  
thirdScore = 75  

list = [firstScore, secondScore, thirdScore]
```

'''

and the csv data is:

```
    Name,first,second,third
    Paul,40,60,30
    Kevin,90,80,75
    Jenny,80,75,90
```

The actual output should be the name which matches the 3 values: `Kevin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)
Can you try this please!

```
import csv

list = [firstScore, secondScore, thirdScore]

with open('test.csv', 'rt') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

# skip the header of your csv
next(reader)

for row in reader:
  if((list[0] == int(row[1])) and (list[1] == int(row[2])) and (list[2] == int(row[3]))):
    # print name (present in first column -> index 0 of the row) 
    print(row[0])
    break
  else:
    print("No match found..")
```

I'm not an expert in Python but if it works don't hesitate to accept as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've edited the if statement to compare list 0 with row 1 and so on, but it did't work. :(

Comment: Just in the function. It does not return the match. I think something's missing in the loop, but I don't know what. I am just starting with Python. Thanks again anyway,  Handler ;)

Comment: Ok i give a try at home, no problem!